# Creating Shapefile/ Feature class from Grid CSV using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, csv

I have csv file which contains data in grid form as:

[image]

I have created a python Script that convert it into below form:

[image]

Is there any tool available within ArcGIS for Desktop that can i used to do my job rather than creating a new script/tool and create vector points geometry in those feature classes.

Comment: It is GIS SE policy to limit each Question to one question. By asking about ArcGIS,  QGIS,  and "any other open source software" you've effectively asked many questions. Please edit your question to focus on one environment.

Answer (score 1):

I belive the only way with an existing tool is [Adding x,y coordinate data as a layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/adding-x-y-coordinate-data-as-a-layer.htm):

> In addition to data sources, such as a shapefile, you can add tabular
>   data that contains geographic locations in the form of x,y coordinates
>   to your map. If the table also contains z-coordinates, such as
>   elevation values, you can add tabular data as 3D content into your
>   globe or scene

The layer can then be exported to a Feature Class.

I think you should go for a python script. Script below will read data stored in a CSV file and create Points in a Point shapefile:

```
import arcpy,csv
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=1
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Temp'
inputcsv=r'C:\Temp\Coordinate.csv'
outputfc = r'outshape.shp'
spatref = r'C:\Temp\SWEREF99TM.prj'

#Create empty point shapefile
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(out_path=r'C:\Temp', out_name=outputfc, geometry_type='POINT', spatial_reference=spatref)
arcpy.AddField_management(outputfc, field_name='Date', field_type='Text', field_length=20)
arcpy.AddField_management(outputfc, field_name='Value', field_type='DOUBLE')

#Read coordinates from csv and insert points in shape. The data is stored as time,x,y,value in the csv
icursor=arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outputfc,['Date','SHAPE@XY','Value'])
with open(inputcsv,'rb') as csvfile:
    for row in csv.reader(csvfile):
        icursor.insertRow([row[0],(float(row[1]),float(row[2])),float(row[3])])
del icursor
```